# Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm trying to upgrade the following template project to ASP.NET Core 1.1:
https://github.com/wilanbigay/aspnet-core-aurelia-typescript-starter

After running dotnet migrate the project.json file has been dropped in favour of the new csproj file.

Using Visual Studio Code and the Nuget4Code extension I've upgraded all components to ASP.NET Core 1.1.

The CsProj now contains entries like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

However I have compilation issues.  It seems the AspNetCore namespace can't be found.  I'm getting the error

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the names pace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I'm not sure how I can check references like I used to be able to in Visual Studio in the references section.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We just had this issue where visual studio helpfully added a local reference rather than going via nuget

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.core\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Removing this and referencing via nuget solved the problem, looks like an issue in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: In mine, this was missing: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" /> altogether. I added it back and it worked. Thanks for giving me a clue as to where to look.

Comment: I'd had a few of these references - seems like they were added automatically as part of the project template?!  Was only an issue when it came to restoring/building on TeamCity.  Removing those references and installing them via NuGet fixed it for me.

Comment: I just added the package I needed which for me was 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />

Comment: I get this:  Determining projects to restore...
  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.

Answer (score 24):

So I guess I was referencing the dependencies but didn't have them installed for the project.

All I needed to do was run
dotnet restore

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore

As stated in the link above this
"Restores the dependencies and tools of a project."

Comment: I'm running .net core 2 where building should restore - ive also done a nuget package restore - and I'm still getting this and many other Identity related errors

Comment: I get 'All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.'

Answer (score 22):

Mine was simply that I had not referenced `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in the .csproj file.

I added the reference and it worked:

**MyTestProject.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. I created the project with `dotnet new web`, perhaps should have used `dotnet new webapp` to add this automatically to .csproj?

Comment: when i double click the .csproj file it appears to open the entire project - how would i edit the .csproj file? you're like saying open the project file in text edit?

Comment: Yes. If you are in visiual studio you can right click the project (in solution explorer) and select edit project or unload project. If you aren't in visual studio open it with VS Code or Notepad++ and you can edit it like any other text file.

Comment: Fixed the issue

Comment: This fixed my issue. What's weird is I've been developing this application for 1 year and just randomly needed to add it.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem as well, and in my case the proper packages were installed and all my `*.csproj` looked correct, but one of the projects in my solution still gave me this error.

A plain `dotnet restore` didn't do the trick for me. 
I had to force a reevaluation of all dependencies like so:

`dotnet restore --force-evaluate`

From the dotnet manual:

> Forces restore to reevaluate all dependencies even if a lock file already exists.

A couple of seconds later, my compiler stopped giving me this error.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this with dotnet core 5.0. My csproj looked like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

But needed to look like (note the project element's sdk attribute):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: more info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview

Answer (score 4):

I had this error upgrading a .NET Core v2.2 project to v3.1. Specifically, a unit testing project was giving the error, that didn't directly use the `AspNetCore` package.

The solution is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework), and consists of modifying the project file to add a `<FrameworkReference>` tag:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

To

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Solved the issue as @dave-glassborow answered

Answer (score 2):

Just adding the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` nuget package fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

What ended up working for me were the following steps:

1. Unload project and edit .csproj file as user875234 recommended in another answer
2. Reload and rebuild project (this resulted in different errors for me)
3. Unload project and undo edits to .csproj file
4. Reload and rebuild project

Along the way, I did also run `dotnet restore` a couple of times, so that may have also helped somehow.

Hopefully this helps someone with a similar issue to me!

Answer (score 2):

For me, using net6, the issue was that Rider did generate this reference in my client library csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>

    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core">

      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.18\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll</HintPath>

    </Reference>

  </ItemGroup>
```

When our build pipeline was running, it was not able to find it so I replaced it with:

```
<ItemGroup>

    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>

  </ItemGroup>
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework

Answer (score 2):

My issue was pretty bizarre.  I have compiled this application a million times and didn't add of remove any packages recently.  Suddenly, I started getting this error.

I noticed in the error, it also referenced a filename just before it.  I went in that file (a class/model) and found a greyed out `using AspNetCore;` - I commented it out and have had no further issues.

None of the other solutions mentioned above helped.  Some even caused more issues.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that a project in the solution was not building properly, so it could not be referenced by other projects in the solution.

The solution was to update Visual Studio *(I updated from version 15.5.6 to version 15.9.1)*. Here is a link to [Microsoft's VS Downloads page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 1):

Just add Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities nuget package

Comment: I then get this error 'the type or namespace Mvc does not exist in the namespace AspNetCore'

Answer (score 1):

I have found this problem when upgrading libraries from .NET Standard 2.0 to 2.1 or .exe's from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1.

The best bet is just to redo all the NuGet includes for the project from scratch. Open the .csproj file in a text editor, and find the section

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

and remove all of it, back to

```
  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>
```

then re-open the solution and reinstall all, and only, the required NuGet packages.

This fixes the problem and can help to clean up any unused package cruft as well!

Answer (score 1):

Adding  NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Add these references to your library when you are using a ASP NET Core library with controllers/MVW:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="7.0.9" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the line '#using AspNetCore;' from my code, issue resolved.

Comment: Consider adding more detailed explanations or providing code examples to enhance the clarity. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403432/how-to-improve-my-answer