# C# Error CS0234 even after adding aspnetcore and extensions packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have a C# code that I am trying to run on VS Code. The steps I went through are as follows:

1. create folder (for this case we will name it "Program") for the program files and then run

> dotnet new console

2. Replace the Program.cs file inside the "Program" folder with the Program.cs file I intend to run ( I did this with earlier C# applications and it worked)
3. Run the following commands to add packages:

> dotnet add package aspnetcore
>
> dotnet add package extensions

All packages above were installed successfully

4. I ran the command

> dotnet build

but received the following errors:

**error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

**error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Please tell me how I am to resolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55264997/10634638

Comment: Add the reference for library

Comment: The csproj file had the line: <PackageReference Include="aspnetcore" Version="0.0.41"> which I changed to <PackageReference Include=Microsoft.AspNetCore.app /> but I got another error:  error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. The 'ItemGroup' start tag on line 8 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'PackageReference'. Line 12, position 7.

Comment: I would suggest just starting with "dotnet new web". Note that the project type is different for ASP.NET Core as well - it's not just adding packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the solution by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) , where I created a new folder and then used the command

> dotnet new web

and managed to create a new ASP.NET Core project, complete with all the necessary libraries and links.

Thanks guys

I then transferred the files and folders I needed into this new folder and