# The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have created a very basic (default) function app using Visual Studio by following [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/develop-test-deploy-azure-functions-with-visual-studio/2-develop-and-test-azure-functions-locally%5D)-

Installed the packages according to the doc only.

After I created a new function app , I am seeing this errors -

[image]

**csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Let me know if anything else I need to provide?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169794/error-cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-aspnetcore-does-not-exist-in-the-name have you tried answers and comments from this queetion?

Comment: Try to restore the nuget package. It seems you are not able to restore the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have the following `Nuget-Package` in the Dependencies.

[image]

If you don't have the `Nuget-package` `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`, please right-click Packages->Manage Nuget-package->Search the package and install it.

[image]

If you already have the `Nuget-package` `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`, please find it in the Installed tab and reinstall it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do not have the required nuget packages installed.

Use the "Manage packages for the solution" to install the missing packages.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#manage-packages-for-the-solution

The picture in the article shows the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" package